# awk to read the file1 and file2 and print difference between two

Tags: awk

I have two files named: File1 & File2 Where File has 100 names while File2 has 1000 names , now I want awk to read the File1 and File2 and print only the names which are there in File2 and not on File1.

Your help & time much appreciated.

```
Example: Below File1 & File2 names...

File1:
karn
steve
vaithee

File2:
vaithee
Karn
steve
niraj
mana
henry

So, Output should be:

niraj
mana
henry
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[tolower($1)];next}!(tolower($1) in a)' file1 file2
```

**Input**

```
$ cat file1
karn
steve
vaithee

$ cat file2
vaithee
Karn
steve
niraj
mana
henry
```

**Output**

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[tolower($1)];next}!(tolower($1) in a)' file1 file2
niraj
mana
henry
```

**Explanation**

- > `FNR==NR`  If the number of records read so far in the current file
  >   is equal to the number of records read so far across all files,
  >   condition which can only be true for the first file read.
- > `a[tolower($1)]` populate array "a" such that the
  >   indexed by the first
  >   field in lowercase from 
  >   current record of file1
- > `next` Move on to the next record so we don't do any processing
  >   intended    for records from the second file.
- > `!(tolower($1) in a)` IF the array `a` index constructed from the
  >   field 1 ($1) in lowercase of the current record of the file2 does not exist (`!`)
  >   in array `a`, we get boolean true **(`!` Called Logical NOT Operator. It is used to reverse the logical state of its operand. If a condition is true, then Logical NOT operator will make it false and vice versa.)** so awk does default operation `print $0` from file2
- > `file1  file2` read file1 and then read file2

Comment: I got the result by `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} !($1 in a){print $1}' File2.txt File1.txt`

Comment: @Karn: I used `tolower` because `Karn != karn`

Comment: @Karn: see above as requested I added explanation